# Generate a random number with 4 digits only

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a batch script that generates random numbers from 1 to 10000.

### My Batch Script

```
@echo off
cls
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM%%%10000+1
echo %RAND%
echo.
pause
```

---

### Current Outputs

```
2532  (4 digits)

253   (3 digits)

25    (2 digits)

2     (1 digits)
```

---

### Expected Outputs

```
2432 (4 digits)

3431 (4 digits)

9282 (4 digits)

8812 (4 digits)
```

---

### Question

I need the random number to be consisted of 4 digits only and not 1, 2, or 3 digits and always 4.

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script#comment6692140_5777608).

Comment: A modulus division by 10000 returns results between 0 and 9999. You add 1. Instead you want results between 1000 and 9999 so the range is less by 1000 and the offset is 1000. You learned the rule of proportion once upon a time ...

Comment: 4 digits ranging from 1000 to 9999, i.e. 9000 numbers. If you take mod by 3 then you get 0, 1, 2. Similarly, you take mod by 9000 and get 0 - 8999. Then add the initial val 1000 to get 1000 - 9999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Generate Random 4-Digit Number Windows Batch Script

You can use a batch script with **Windows** to complete this task easily as I'll explain below.

> **Essentially this will. . .**
>
> 1. Use **PowerShell's**
>      [Get-Random](https://ss64.com/ps/get-random.html) function to
>      generate the random number
>
>    - The random number value will be in a range of `0000-9999` using the `-Maximum` and `-Minimum` parameters
> 2. Use the ["0" Custom Specifier—"{0:0000} -f $fRandom"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier)
>      with [**PowerShell** and
>      **.NET**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx) to ensure the random number value has leading zeros added ensuring it
>      always has 4 digits
> 3. Result in the **PowerShell** random number value being `echo`'d as the output
> 4. Use a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to take the result of the executed **PowerShell** script (*the random number*)
>      within it, and save that result as a variable to use in the batch
>      script for your needs (`%RAND%`)

---

### Batch Script

*If the random number cannot be 4-digit values with prefixed zeros like `0001`, `0011`, or `0111` you can change the **`-Minimum 1000`** like that instead but random digits `1-999` will be omitted so the value of **`1000`** is what you want to use for the `-Minimum` parameter if that's the case.*

```
 @ECHO ON

 SET PSScript=%Temp%\~tmpRandom4Digit.ps1
 IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"

 ECHO $fRandom = Get-Random -Maximum 9999 -Minimum 0000>>"%PSScript%"
 ECHO $Random  = "{0:0000}" -f $fRandom>>"%PSScript%"
 ECHO ECHO $Random>>"%PSScript%"

 SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 
 CD /D "%PowerShellDir%" 
 FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"') DO SET "RAND=%%A"

 echo %RAND%

 EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Get-Random](https://ss64.com/ps/get-random.html)
- [Using .NET to Format Numbers in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx)
- [The "0" Custom Specifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier)
- 

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be to take the last digit of four random generated numbers

```dos
set "RAND=%random:~-1%%random:~-1%%random:~-1%%random:~-1%"
```

Comment: very clever. brevity is king!

Answer (score 0):

Your could use my batch script:

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "/?" (
echo Usage:
echo.
echo random [min] [max]
echo random /?
echo.
echo Can be used to generate a random number between [min] - [max] and displays the output in the RDM variable.
echo./? can be used to display help
echo.
echo Examples:
echo.
echo random 1 5 - Generates a random number between 1 - 5
echo random /? - Displays help
)
if not "%1" == "/?" set /a rdm=(%random%*%2/32768)+%1
```

Then drag in the C:\Windows\System32 Folder and type "random /?" for the syntax.

Comment: Nice, worked for me. You can add an echo %rdm% to print the value

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the minimum value and the range on your initial solution.

```
@echo off
cls
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM%%%9000+1000
echo %RAND%
echo.
pause
```